# Треугольники из radio input

Tags: html, table, radio

Есть варианты как сверстать это внутри ячейки таблицы?

[image: треугольники]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="cell">
        <input type="radio" checked/><br/>
        <input type="radio" checked/>
        <input type="radio" checked/><br/>
        <input type="radio" checked/>
        <input type="radio" checked/>
        <input type="radio" checked/><br/>
      </div><br/>
      <div class="cell">
        <input type="radio" checked/><br/>
        <input type="radio" checked/>
        <input type="radio" checked/><br/>
        <input type="radio" checked/>
        <input type="radio" checked/>
        <input type="radio" checked/><br/>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <input type="radio" checked/><br/>
        <input type="radio" checked/>
        <input type="radio" checked/><br/>
        <input type="radio" checked/>
        <input type="radio" checked/>
        <input type="radio" checked/><br/>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Без css:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="radio" checked/><br/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="radio" checked/>
      <input type="radio" checked/>
      <br/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="radio" checked/>
      <input type="radio" checked/>
      <input type="radio" checked/>
      <br/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="radio" checked/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="radio" checked/>
      <br/> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="radio" checked/>
      <input type="radio" checked/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="radio" checked/>
      <input type="radio" checked/>
      <br/>
      <input type="radio" checked/>
      <input type="radio" checked/>
      <input type="radio" checked/>
      <input type="radio" checked/>
      <input type="radio" checked/>
      <input type="radio" checked/>
      <br/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

В ячейке 3 блока `div` . В первом 1 `input` , во втором - 2 и третьем - 3. Далее выравнивание ячейки `text-align: center`

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
      <div>
        <input type="radio">
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio">
        <input type="radio">
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio">
        <input type="radio">
        <input type="radio">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ну как сверстать 1 блок понятно, а вот как под ним разместить еще 2 таких, причем что бы первый оставался по центру. без использования css

Comment: @Helmoz "без использования css" - может еще и без html, и без компьютера? Вы уж скажите сразу, что еще нельзя использовать.

Comment: Если сможете без html, хех вперед. Просто есть задача которую я пытаюсь решить, но табличная верстка это какой-то ужас, если у вас нет решения, зачем писать бесполезные комментарии?

Comment: @Helmoz Мои комментарии принесли (и продолжают приносить) пользу и радость тысячам посетителей https://ru.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @Igor Очень рад за вас, надеюсь найдется решение и этой задачи, потому как блоками с использованием css сам смог, а вот не используя css и div не получается.

Comment: @Helmoz мне интересно почему нельзя использовать CSS и div?